How would I convert this to a perforated circuit board?
How would I go about converting this schematic to perforated circuit board? For example, how would I connect the battery to the op amp?


Uhhh…your fake split supply rails aren’t going to work very well. What is output intended to go to?

Kyle, redesign the circuit to make better use of the 9 V supply. This means using the resistor divider at the (+) input of the opamp, for example. And not to create a ground return.  Then just connect the (-) of the battery to the (-) supply lead of the opamp and the (+) of the battery to the (+) supply lead of the opamp.

By perforated circuit board, do you mean a breadboard? If yes, strips or just holes? Or do you mean printed circuit board as in a custom PCB for your design?

Let me give you a general idea about how you can put your circuit into a PCB.
Understand the requirements. I mean the electrical parameters. Like maximum current, voltage, any particular impedance requirements etc.
Create the schematic. You can use Kicad for schematic capture.
Do a schematic review.
Create PCB stackup.
Define your design rules.
Place and route.
Drill holes.
Layout review.
Add all the required labels and other identifiers that will improve the readability of your schematic and layout. This will make layout review much faster.
Do DFM (Design for Manufacturability) and DFA (Design for Assembly). Sometimes called DFMA(Design for Manufacturability and Assembly).
Generate netlist and send it for fab. At the same time you can order the components.
Once the board come from fab do the bare board testing.
Bare board testing is done means you can send board and components to assembly house.
Once the board come from assembly do the visual inspection first after that check the impedances across decaps.
After this you can power on the board with minimal current.
Check al voltage rails are coming or not.
After that you can start the functional testing.

Sounds like a lot but really it’s a few methodical steps.  Once you’ve done it a few times it comes very naturally.  Don’t try do do everything at once or you’ll get into a hopeless mess

I approve with everything except that DFM/DFA is a process /step/. DFM DFA should be kept as a guiding principle through the whole design process, both in system design, circuit design and layout.

First make sure to follow the advice from your previous question, especially about the bypassing R1-v and R2-v like so:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Then you should probably build the circuit on a breadboard such as this one to test it and make sure it works as expected.
From there you can go on to building it on a perf board. They have boards that match the pattern of the breadboards, such as this one. These make transferring the circuit easy, just layout the parts the same way as on the breadboard and solder them to the circuit board. There are power buses at the top and bottom and columns of connected pins so you can mount ICs such as your opamp in the middle and connect to them. you might want to use a socket for the opamp to make it easy to replace or try different types of opamps to see which sounds best.
